# How to display an output from a game engine?

Tags: graphics, directx, sdl, d

I worked out most of the logic for a retro-styled 2D game engine, but I don't know how to display its output.

Basically it generates a low-res bitmap with its logic similar to how most systems did(use of sprites, palettes, etc). As I haven't learned DirectX or similar, I don't have an hdea how should I can get displayed its output and update it regularly (tied to the VSync?). I'm working with D, but if you know C or C++ that's also fine.

EDIT: Okay, I'm rewriting it to work with SDL. How should I make the output format? Creating an array with the data?

Comment: Does the generated bitmap capture the whole screen? You could just use a display lib that shows it on a regular timer. My simpledisplay.d has the functions to do it, but it might not be obvious how.

Comment: I would look into SFML, Allegro or SDL to help start you off in displaying graphics.

Answer (score 4):

Look into SDL2. It is the de-facto standard for cross-platform games (currently being developed mainly by Valve). It can also be used as a base if you later want to use OpenGL or D3D. Note that OpenGL is *much* more popular and well supported in the D community.

To actually put the bitmap on the screen, you simply need to copy it to the screen with SDL, or with OpenGL/D3D, copy it into a texture and display that texture on 2 triangles. But I think plain SDL should be enough in your case.

[This seems like what you need](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy)
(you might need to scale the bitmap to match window/screen size, though)

D has the [Derelict](http://derelictorg.github.io/) ([@github](https://github.com/DerelictOrg)) ([how to use with DUB](http://dblog.aldacron.net/derelict-help/using-derelict/)) project which includes bindings to [SDL](http://code.dlang.org/packages/derelict-sdl2), [OpenGL](http://code.dlang.org/packages/derelict-gl3), various SDL extensions (SDL-TTF, SDL-Mixer, SDL-Image, etc. - included in the SDL binding), [FreeType](http://code.dlang.org/packages/derelict-ft) (fonts), [Assimp](http://code.dlang.org/packages/derelict-assimp3) (3D model formats) and so on. The bindings are designed to be identical to use as the original C/C++ libraries, which may not be as nice as pure D-style wrappers but it means C/C++ tutorials for those libraries can still be used.

I also made a little [tutorial](http://defenestrate.eu/_static/ossvikend/intro-gamedev-d/slides/index.html#1) for making a game with SDL/Derelict/GFM (GFM is a more D-style library), but as GFM is very much a work in progress right now the tutorial may already be a bit outdated. Derelict, on the other hand, has been stable and maintained for well over 10 years now.

- [SDL2 reference](https://wiki.libsdl.org/APIByCategory)
- SDL2 tutorials (for C++, but usable with D due to Derelict's design) : [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) and [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials)

EDIT: added more links
EDIT2: note about actually displaying the output

Answer (score 1):

Just search for a library like SDL, SFML or Allegro,
I never tried D but i once heard of someone who used it with SDL.

Edit: Check [this](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~cs8k-cyu/windows/tt_e.html) open-source game in D

Comment: That is really, *really* old. From way back in D1 times.